# mongodb set null in update

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have to interchange the values of a document.

```
var query = {"_id" : ObjectId("53e1c254382f891cc600076d")};

db.properties.find(query).forEach(function(prop){
   printjson({"_id":prop._id, "val":prop.val, "ua":prop.ua});
   db.properties.update(query, {$set:{ua: prop.val}},{$unset:{val:""}});
});
```

Before update operation, document looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53e1c254382f891cc600076d"),
    "val" : 9876541,
    "ua" : null
}
```

And after the update it turns to:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53e1c254382f891cc600076d"),
    "val" : 9876541,
    "ua" : 9876541
}
```

But I expect it as:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53e1c254382f891cc600076d"),
    "val" : null,
    "ua" : 9876541
}
```

But its not working. also setting `"val"` null `({$set:{val:null}})` directly it deleted my entire document.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Setting `undefined`, It worked like a charm!!

```
db.properties.find(query).forEach(function(prop){
    db.properties.update(query, {$set:{ua: prop.val, val:undefined}}); 
});
```

Comment: is it possible to do this except last two created documents ?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but your syntax for the update function is wrong. The update object should be one single object: `db.properties.update(query, {{$set:{ua: prop.val}},{$unset:{val:""}}});`

Comment: That could be newer update w.r.t syntaxes, I really doubt if that syntax was available at that time. I was using monogdb 2.2 at that time.btw thanks for the answer, hope it will help someone

Comment: Now if I have to update val field, will val still be available in document.