# Date field in mongodb not get update when sending a null value

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose

I have developed a mean stack application. I am trying to update a record with a null value for the Date field. This is working fine on my localhost but not on my server (Aws Ec2). It contains the previous value before the update.

I have also tried 'undefined' but still same issue.

Visit [mongodb set null in update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30122484/mongodb-set-null-in-update)

```
router.put('/editAssign/:id',(req,res)=>{
    if(!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id))
        return res.status(400).send('No record with given id : $(req.params.id)');

    var assignment = {
        name: req.body.name,
        code: req.body.code,
        appointmentTime: req.body.appointmentTime,
        scheduledTime:req.body.scheduledTime,
        countEndTime: null
    };

    Assignment.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id,{$set:assignment},{new:true},(err,doc)=>{
        if(!err)
            res.send(doc);
        else
            console.log('Error in Assignment Update: '+JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2));
    });
});
```

I expect it to work on my server too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done a similar thing with updating the last login date of a user when they log in using Mongoose.

```
const authUser: any = await new Promise((res, rej) => {
    User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: user[0]._id }, { last_login: date }, {new: true}, (err: any, user:any) => {
        if (err) rej(err);
        res(user);
    });
});
```

As you can see I wrapped it in a promise so i can wait for the response for sending back.

From looking at yours I would it looks like you are not telling it to look for using `findByIdAndUpdate` and not `findOneAndUpdate` because you are only passing in the ID. So the updated should look like this.

```
Assignment.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, assignment, {new:true}, (err,doc)=>{
    if(err) console.log('Error in Assignment Update: '+JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2));

    return res.send(doc);
});
```

So in the one above, we are passing over the ID for `findByIdAnyUpdate` and we are just passing in the assignment. which if it includes all the same fields as the schema it will just update with the latest fields.

**EDIT:**

One other method you could try is:

```
Assignment.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, assignment, {new: true}, (err: any, result: any) => {
    if(err) console.log('Error in Assignment Update: '+JSON.stringify(err,undefined,2));

    // Reasign with new assignment and save
    result = assignment;
    result.save();

    return res.send(result);
});
```

Comment: THen why it is working fine on my localhost?
I have applied your solution too but the same problem is persisting on my server but not on localhost.

Comment: Let me see if this is happening on my server too

Comment: Your solution is also correct. My server is doing some strange issue.
It is updating appointmentTime but not countEndTime. Both are of same date type.

Comment: Take a look at another method I have used to update with mongoose

Comment: Check your version of mongo on your machine and on the serve

Comment: THANKS, you saved my day!
My localhost MongoDB version was 4.0.0 and on my server, it was 3.6 
Now I updated it to 4.0.0.

Comment: Your welcome dude, Had some of the same problems myself with getting it all setup and ordered.